# Get Auto-Rotate Information On Android

Tags: android, rotation, screen

I am working on an app for Android, for which I would like to know whether or not Auto-Rotate is enabled. Does anybody know how I can get this? So just for clarity: I only need to know whether or not a user has Auto-Rotate enabled in their settings or not.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can Get Auto-Rotate Information On/Off Using `Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION` as :

```
if (android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(),Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION, 0) == 1){
 Toast.makeText(Rotation.this, "Rotation ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
else{
 Toast.makeText(Rotation.this, "Rotation OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```