# is it possible to detect android orientation without AUTO ROTATION ON?

Tags: android

i want to use a service to detect the orientation. But by using broadcaster listening to CONFIGURATION_CHANGED or onConfigurationChanged, it only works if the auto rotation is on.
So is there a way to detect the orientation without the auto rotation on?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12867236/get-auto-rotate-information-on-android

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But that is not what i want. I want to determine the orientation when is auto rotation is OFF.